# capybara webkit js form submit hangs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Have a basic simpleform.

Which submits OK in the browser.

And have a test for that form, which just fills in all the fields and hits 'submit'.

It crashes when test is set to `js: true`

Any thoughts?

`js: true` has to be set because of a few reasons.

Test was passing before I had to set `js: true`

Comment: Can you give us something more than that? Some specific code about your capybara setup? Are you using testunit, rspec? What does the html look like that you are trying to submit?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding this to my RSpec:

```
  after(:each) do
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
  end
```